# Do virtual images exist in the real world?

Tags: visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses, vision

I have been reading an article here in physics stack exchange that talks about if it is possible to see virtual images, and i read an answer saying it is actually your brain that understands the refracted rays and creates the image, but in high school class I remember this image of converging lenses.[image: what happens when an object is put between the focus and the lens[1]]
As it can be seen we projected the refracted rays back to form the virtual image. so I just want to clear my confusion does this really happen in the real world or is this a way we humans have developed in order to understand what happens. and can we see the object if it is put in this position, if so how would that be (how does the eye do it if there is no canvas for the image to be formed and reflect). And one more question if the image were to be seen at all in what direction should be the viewer be, on the left or the right?